# Client crash occurring against moderately large data

Tags: google-chrome, neo4j

I have loaded up a database with about 7.5M nodes having 33+M relationships - it's about 25 GB in total. So, it's reasonably large is my point. What I am finding since loading it is that periodically my Neo4j client is just falling over, leaving nothing more than Chrome's irritating "Aw snap - something went wrong" behind. I have checked the logs and found nothing significant there. How can I begin to track down what is happening on these failed queries?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with your Chrome environment. [This Google support page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/WMxdeZPUazc) on the "Aw Snap!" error may be of help.

Also, if your queries return a lot of data or take too long to respond, the browser might be running out of memory or exceeding some internal timeouts. So, make sure the queries you make via a browser are tailored accordingly.

Comment: I tried all the solutions proposed for Chrome - none helped. So I tried running against a Firefox browswer. Now it doesn't crash, it hangs... I let a query run overnight and it still never resolved. My issue is, I can't find anything in the logs that offers any explanation of what's going on. Very frustrating!